# Default parameter - CancellationToken

Tags: c#, .net, cancellation, cancellation-token

I use the following code:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string msg, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
```

But I think this is wrong, because if the caller calls `SendMessage` without providing a cancellation token the code will run with the default which is the same as `CancellationToken.None`, so it will wait without time expiration.

So maybe this is better:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string msg, CancellationToken ct)
```

What do you think?

Comment: *"It’s a good idea to only make your* `CancellationToken` *parameters optional in your public API (if you have one) and leave them as required parameters everywhere else."* -- answer and link to article provided in the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It really depends on your implementation of the method... Take a look below:

> **Optional CancellationToken parameter**
>
> If you want to accept CancellationToken but want to make it optional,
>   you can do so with syntax such as this:
>
> ```
> public Task SomethingExpensiveAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
> {
>    // don’t worry about NullReferenceException if the
>    // caller omitted the argument because it’s a struct.
>    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
> }
> ```
>
> **It’s a good idea to only make your CancellationToken parameters
>   optional in your public API (if you have one) and leave them as
>   required parameters everywhere else.** This really helps to ensure that
>   you intentionally propagate your CancellationTokens through all the
>   methods you call (#2 above). But of course remember to switch to
>   passing `CancellationToken.None` once you pass the point of no
>   cancellation.
>
> It’s also a good API pattern to keep your CancellationToken as the
>   last parameter your method accepts. This fits nicely with optional
>   parameters anyway since they have to show up after any required
>   parameters.

*Taken from MSDN: [Recommended patterns for CancellationToken](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewarnottms/2014/03/19/recommended-patterns-for-cancellationtoken/)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you want caller always pass CancelationToken, you must force it with explicit parameter:

```
public async Task SendMessage(string msg, CancellationToken ct)
```

Of cause, caller can pass `CancellationToken.None`, but it's not your choice. You create "contract" that requires `CancellationToken`.